# When using media-breakpoint-down, the classes aren't generated

Tags: sass, bootstrap-5

While

```
@each $breakpoint in map-keys($grid-breakpoints) {
    $infix: breakpoint-infix($breakpoint, $grid-breakpoints);
    @include media-breakpoint-up($breakpoint) {
        .text-truncate#{$infix} {
            overflow: hidden;
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
        }
    }
}
```

works, this one doesn't:

```
@each $breakpoint in map-keys($grid-breakpoints) {
    $infix: breakpoint-infix($breakpoint, $grid-breakpoints);
    @include media-breakpoint-down($breakpoint) {
        .text-truncate#{$infix} {
            overflow: hidden;
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
        }
    }
}
```

It compiles as usual, but I don't see the classes.

Comment: can you also add `$grid-breakpoints` in the code you have provided ?

Comment: I'm using the default breakpoints